# Listen for added table rows

Tags: jquery

Lets say i have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr></tr>
</table>

$(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(){
         $('table').append('<tr><input class="remove" value="remove"></tr>');
    });

    $('.remove').on('click', function(){

         $(this).parent().remove();
   });

});
```

Is there any way to bind a custom event handler that triggers whenever a row is added or removed, using jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding the rows? Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can bind custom event.

```
$('#table_id').bind('rowAddOrRemove', function(event){
    //do what you want.
});
```

And when you add or remove a row, you should trigger the event.

```
$('#table_id').trigger('rowAddOrRemove');
```

Comment: I don't think this offers too much. If you have to trigger the even manually then you might as well call a function instead. It does answer the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the method when you remove the rows? Let's say you have a function that allows you to remove a row. In that function just call the method you would've used for your listener. Same with adding rows.

```
$(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
        // insert your method here...
    });

});
```