# jQuery: clone newest row in table -- not last row, newest

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table

I have a form that adds rows to a table upon submit:

```
<form id="scan_form" name="scan_form" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/app/app.pl" onsubmit="return checkout('f00b@r');">
```

**Sidenote**
Want to add/append to submit function as follows without "disturbing" its existing functionality:

```
$("#scan_form").submit(function() {
    //clone row and add to hidden table.
});
```

When it adds a row, I'd like it to add that same row to a different hidden table for printing.

I'm thinking I need to somehow bind a function to the table that adds this same row to a different table but am stuck. Using the below SO question as a template, how do I capture this newest row?

[Listen for added table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095472/listen-for-added-table-rows)

```
$('#table_id').bind('rowAddOrRemove', function(event){
    //do what you want.
});
```

The table is sorted alphabetically, so the newest row won't necessarily be the last row.

**UPDATE**
Trying this idea:

Step 1: Set id of all existing rows to 'oldRow'

```
$( '#loanTable tr' ).attr("id", "oldRow");
```

Step 2: Clone table above:

```
var lbl = $("#loanTable tbody");
var newLbl = $(lbl[0].outerHTML);
```

Step 3: Delete rows with id 'oldRow'

```
$(".oldRow", newLbl).remove();
```

As you surmised, it deleted everything. How do I connect these dots?

**UPDATE 2**
How do I do the following?

```
$('#table_id').bind('rowAddOrRemove', function(event){
        //add attribute print to 'this' row.
});
```

Want to label new rows added to table.

Comment: Consider adding a timestamp to the rows (perhaps a data-attribute?) - then it can be used for sorting, or finding and deleting.

Comment: @pst - I could add this timestamp to existing rows, then just copy the rows that do not have this id or stamp? Brilliant!!!!!!! If this works you should make this an answer ...much simpler than the direction I was going. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create new rows with some class, say '.newRow', that on event you should remove this class to be prepared for the next insert:

```
$('#table_id .newRow').trigger('rowAddOrRemove');

$('#table_id').bind('rowAddOrRemove', function(event){
   //do what you want.
   $(this).removeClass('.newRow');
});
```

Comment: I think I'm going to try this in reverse. Flag existing rows as 'old', clone the whole table, delete 'old' rows in new table leaving the 'new' ones.

Comment: If it suits your logic more... Hope it will help